# Why is class midpoint an important concept?

Tags: frequency

Why do we need the concept of a class midpoint (frequency distribution) in the study of statistics?

What does it achieve?

Comment: 1. Is this for a class? 2. I don't accept the premise -- I wouldn't say it's an *important* concept. It's relevant to a number of situations where you might have binning in  calculations (e.g. of a histogram or just a table of frequencies).

Comment: Count me having no idea what a class midpoint is as evidence towards it's possible unimportance.  Maybe?